# How to compare two key and value and find max key value from array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, filter

I need solution for How to compare two key and value and find max key value from array.

explain:- I have below array in this if **url** and **con code** both are same than higher **amount** array should display and unmatch data should be display please provide  sollution for same .

```
$array = array( 
  array(
    "id" => 1, 
    "amount" => 10,
    "url" => 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.heroesofutopia',
    "con" => array('US' =>array('id'=> '1','code'=>'US')),
    ),
    array( 
    "id" => 2, 
    "amount" => 3,
    "url" => 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.heroesofutopia'  ,
    "con" => array('US' =>array('id'=> '1','code'=>'US')),  
    ),
     array( 
    "id" => 3, 
    "amount" => 19,
    "url" => 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.heroesofutopia'  ,
    "con" => array('US' =>array('id'=> '1','code'=>'US'),'Uk' =>array('id'=> '2','code'=>'UK')),    
    ),  
    array( 
    "id" => 4, 
    "amount" => 50,
    "url" => 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.heroesofutopia1111'  ,
    "con" => array('US' =>array('id'=> '1','code'=>'US'),'Uk' =>array('id'=> '2','code'=>'UK')),    
    ),            
);
```

Please check result i want 
in this example 1 and 2 id have same url and country code so from this two we have to choose higher amount one.so we choose this and id 3 and 4 are not match this criteria so its will remain same in this array because ID 3 has same url but has different country code and ID 4 has different url.

i want this result.please provide sollution for same,
thanks in advance...!!

```
array(  "id" => 1, 
        "amount" => 10,
        "url" => 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.heroesofutopia',
        "con" => array('US' =>array('id'=> '1','code'=>'US')),
        ),
 array( 
        "id" => 3, 
        "amount" => 19,
        "url" => 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.heroesofutopia'  ,
        "con" => array('US' =>array('id'=> '1','code'=>'US'),'Uk' =>array('id'=> '2','code'=>'UK')),    
        ),  
 array( 
        "id" => 4, 
        "amount" => 50,
        "url" => 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.heroesofutopia1111'  ,
        "con" => array('US' =>array('id'=> '1','code'=>'US'),'Uk' =>array('id'=> '2','code'=>'UK')),    
        ),
```

My code is for that is

```
$output = [];
foreach($array as $data){   

       if(!isset($output[$data['url']]) ){          

            $output[$data['url']] = $data;

        }
        elseif( $output[$data['url']]['amount'] < $data['amount']){

            $output[$data['url']] = $data;
        }

    }
echo "<pre>"; print_r($output);
```

Comment: We help here but we don't write code for others  .. so what did you tried ?

Comment: I have make this code but its not provide result which i want.
so please help me out for this.
$output = [];
foreach($array as $data){   
   
       if(!isset($output[$data['url']]) ){        
   
         $output[$data['url']] = $data;
        
     }
     elseif( $output[$data['url']]['amount'] < $data['amount']){
      
         $output[$data['url']] = $data;
     }
                            
    }
echo "<pre>"; print_r($output);

Answer (score 0):

This is correct answer

```
$output = array_reduce($array, function ($carry, $itemA) {
    return array_filter($carry, function ($itemB) use($itemA) {
        return ( 
            $itemB['url'] != $itemA['url']
            || $itemB['con'] != $itemA['con']
            || $itemB['amount'] >= $itemA['amount']
        );
    });
}, $array);
```